# Android archive text ressource returns path to an image ressource

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources, aar

I just uploaded an Android archive successfully to maven, now in a fast test it compiled fine. But on rumtime is not my error message printed instead it is a path to a image ressource of another Android archive (I guess the appcompat library). However I use a call like this in my library:

```
String error = res.getString(R.string.some_error, some, args, are, possible);
editText.setError(error);
```

Here is the resulting image:

[image: Wrong error message]

Any idea how to fix this? If I reference my project in gradle with project instead of a normal dependency it works fine.

If you want to see my actual code it is on GitHub. The related lines are [292](https://github.com/rekire/EditMail/blob/master/EditMailLibrary/src/main/java/eu/rekisoft/android/editmail/EditMail.java#L292) and [242](https://github.com/rekire/EditMail/blob/master/EditMailLibrary/src/main/java/eu/rekisoft/android/editmail/EditMail.java#L242).

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question itself, not on an external site.

Comment: I did, the other code is not really relevant. That two lines of code creates the given image